# typescript reporting error with react native stylesheet

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a stylesheet I am importing from a global stylesheet file `styles.ts` into `home.ts`

```
// styles.ts
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export default {
  text: StyleSheet.create({
    body: {
      color: 'red',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  })
}

// home.ts

import globalStyles from '../constants/styles'

render() {
  return <Text style={globalStyles.text.body}>Hello, tap begin to start Lesson 1</Text>
}
```

but even though the text renders correctly in the ios simulator, typescript is complaining, saying

```
file: 'file:///Users/matthewchung/Documents/Cards/src/screens/HomeScreen.tsx'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Type '{ style: { color: string; textAlign: string; }; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<TextProperties, ComponentState>> & Reado...'.
  Type '{ style: { color: string; textAlign: string; }; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<TextProperties>'.
    Types of property 'style' are incompatible.
      Type '{ color: string; textAlign: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TextStyle'.
        Types of property 'textAlign' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"center" | "auto" | "left" | "right"'.'
```

and I'm not sure why. anyways, any suggestions are appreciated.